# Spring overriding the RequestToViewNameTranslator

Tags: java, spring, configuration

Overriding the RequestToViewNameTranslator appears to be harder than what I thought. There are only a few example online.

The formula was pretty simple, register a bean in the @Configuration, the bean must implements the interface RequestToViewNameTranslator. Then, override the method getViewName.

I can break when I register the bean in the class ViewConfiguration.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class ViewConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ViewNameResolver viewNameResolver() {
        return new ViewNameResolver();
    }
}
```

But the method getViewName is never called.

```
public class ViewNameResolver implements RequestToViewNameTranslator {

    @Override
    public String getViewName(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        return "test";
    }
}
```

Perhaps someone can point me out why the method getViewName is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add @Component("viewNameTranslator") over the class ViewNameResolver. You can also remove the bean registration in ViewConfiguration as it is useless. I don't really understand why, but it works. If someone has an explanation feel free to write it.